# I'm writing AVR assembly in atmel, but "call" instruction doesn't work

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega, atmel

I'm using Atmel Studio 6.2 to write some assembly code for Atmega328p.

However, the `call` instruction for subroutine doesn't work when I use simulator and step-by-step execute the program. It completely ignores the `call` instruction and goes on to the next line.

In order to test the `call` instruction I wrote a simple program, which looks as follows:

```
.include "m328pdef.inc"

ldi R16, 11
call hello_world
mov R1, R0
nop

hello_world:
    mov R0, R16
    ret
```

But even this doesn't work! It just goes on to execute `mov R1, R0`.
What might be the reason? It's so annoying when `call` doesn't work!

Comment: In the debugger, do you use the command “step” or the command “next?”

Comment: I'm asking because typically debuggers have both a command that goes to the next instruction executed by the processor and a command that executes until the next line of code in your program (e.g. after `hello_world` completed execution).

Comment: ooohh!!! I'm just stupid!! yes i'm stupid!!! when it's call, i should click 'step into' !!!!! it works now T.T i have to bump my head into wall for the stupidity!!!! thanks a lot :) :) :)

Comment: So in that "stupid simple program" you could have did `ldi R16,5` in `hello_world:` and see if the `R16` did or didn't change after `call`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.include "m328pdef.inc"
ldi r16,11 
ldi r17,0
ldi r18,1
rcall hello_world
mov r16,r17
nop

hello world:
mov r16,r18
ret
```

I am using r16,r17, and r18 because its general use registers, only use it for debugging.
here is the step by step explanation:
1. load immediate value "11" to r16
2. load immediate value "0" to r17
3. load immediate value "1" to r18
4. call hello_world label. push address into stack
5. move value from r18 (1) to r16, so r16 value is 1
6. ret, pop the address, and goes back
7. move value from r17 (0) to r16, r16 value is 0

If you run the program at once instead of step-by-step, you wont know the difference.
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You have to define stack
http://www.avr-tutorials.com/assembly/writing-assembly-subroutines-avr-microcontroller

```
;Initialize the microcontroller stack pointer
                LDI    R16, low(RAMEND)
                OUT    SPL, R16
                LDI    R16, high(RAMEND)
                OUT    SPH, R16
```